# how to use terms query in elasticsearch 7.x in this case

Tags: java, elasticsearch

elasticsearch version is 7.x

here has some nested data blow :

```
data1:
[{name:"tom"},{name:"jack"}]

data2:
[{name:"tom"},{name:"rose"}]

data3:
[{name:"tom"},{name:"rose3"}]
...

dataN:
[{name:"tom"},{name:"roseN"}]
```

when i use the terms query , **I just want to search tom, jack, But don't want to include rose...roseN**

```
query:{
terms:{["tom","jack"]}
}
this code is not effective
```

Comment: any body else has some other ideas ? thx

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example

**Index Data:**

```
PUT /_doc/1
{
  "names": [
    {
      "name": "tom"
    },
    {
      "name": "jack"
    }
  ]
}

PUT /_doc/2
{
  "names": [
    {
      "name": "tom"
    },
    {
      "name": "rose"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "terms": {
          "names.name": [
            "tom",
            "jack"
          ]
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "names.name": "rose"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65838516",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "names": [
            {
              "name": "tom"
            },
            {
              "name": "jack"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: this query will show the name rose , but i just want tom and jack to show

Comment: @reesechou2014 please go through the updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: can i only use terms to implement it ? i dont want to use so many  must_not , because my data is  dynamic, maybe the data3, data4 has other name like rose1,rose2..

Comment: @reesechou2014 I don't think there is any other way, you can achieve your use case by using multiple `must_not` OR you can use script query to achieve your use case

Comment: @reesechou2014 If my answer helped you, then please don't forget to upvote the answer as well 